# How to speed up this code VBA

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

This code is very straightforward if any cell in the range is changed it should put date and time in the col A of that row.

> This takes too long for larger range I tried to exit sub after the IF statement but it gets slow and EXCEL stops responding until it has finished with the code

```
   Option Explicit
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim Cel As Range
        Dim m As Long

        For Each Cel In Range("B2:Z104857")
            If Not Intersect(Target, Cel) Is Nothing Then
                m = Cel.Row
                With ActiveSheet.Range("A" & m)
                    .Value = Date & " " & Time
                    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM "
                End With
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next Cel
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `Target` is smaller than `Range("B2:Z104857")` (which is a *huge* range)

So if you replace the line:

```
For Each Cel In Range("B2:Z104857")
```

by

```
For Each Cel In Target
```

you should get a dramatic speedup.

Also -- it can't hurt to put

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

at the beginning of your sub and

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

at the end.

On Edit: @CharlesWilliams points out that it is also a good idea to add the line  `Application.EnableEvents=False` at the start of the sub and `Appication.EnableEvents=True` at the end. This is because event handlers can sometimes lead to cascading behavior whereby event handlers make changes which trigger other event handlers (which maybe trigger still other event handlers ...).

Comment: Do I have to define `Target` as Range and assign it before replacing?

Comment: The event handler passes you `Target` -- you don't need to do anything to give it a value.

Comment: Thank you very much I guess my Basics are still not clear.

Comment: Add Application.EnableEvents=False at the start and Appication.EnableEvents=True at the end to minimise the effect of adding the time-stamp triggering the change event

Answer (score 1):

Can you just check target.column within your constraints, the same with rows, then cells(target.Row,1).value=now?

```
If (target.column>=2 and target.column<=26) and (target.row>=2 and target.row<=10000) then cells(target.Row,1).value =now
```